# How to determine the value of key pressed in Windows Phone 7 Numeric Keyboard?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I hooked up an event handler to the `KeyDown` event of a TextBox. The event handler has an argument of type `KeyEventArgs` with properties `Key` and `PlatformKeyCode`. The issue is for both the <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>!</kbd> keys pressed on the windows phone soft keyboard, the values for Key and `PlatformKeyCode` are `D1` and `49` respectively. I cant tell which key was pressed. Also the `Keyboard.Modifiers` static property returns "*None*"

So how do I determine the key that was pressed?

Comment: I thought this would be easy - but I just tested this on my device, and I get the same results. I also notice that the keys `;` and `:` both have the same PlatformKeyCode of 186 and `Key == Key.Unknown`. Weird.

Comment: @driis Thanks for testing and confirming my suspicions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue.

[KeyDown/OnKeyDown and KeyUp/OnKeyUp issues](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/5c1629e2-79f4-489e-99ad-f67dda313329)

You could always read the input values instead and act on 1 / ! seperately.

Comment: Agreed, feel free to post it on connect and/or the official suggestions forum.

Answer (score 1):

This very much looks like a bug.

This exists on both the emulator and real devices.

If using the pc keyboard with the emulator the modifier keys are detected on key down so this won't work.

Interestingly, if using a device with a physical keyboard, if the function/shift button is enabled it triggers 2 keydown events when the other button is pressed. One for the correct keycode and one for the modifier key but Keboard.Modifier always equals "None".

It looks like you need to read the textbox value before and after the TextChanged event.

Comment: thanks for the experiments and suggestions. I am working with the TextChanged event now to overcome the limitation