# WP7 TextBox how to detect key up is alphabet or punctuation mark

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, keyup, punctuation, alphabet

I want filter a `ListBox` based on what user types in the `TextBox`, so I handle the `TextBox_KeyUp` event. `TextBox_OnTextChanged` doesnot suit my need.

My Windows Phone device has a physical keyboard. So I must exclude keys like Escape, F1, F2, Unknown, ... But this doesnot work since I want to handle character like , [ ] ` @ ... but they are all expressed as Unknown !

I only want to detect which that key up is alphabet or punctuation mark, and discard other cases. How to do that ?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328904/how-to-determine-the-value-of-key-pressed-in-windows-phone-7-numeric-keyboard.